# Getting error SDK licenses have not been accepted

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

Before marking it as duplicate question please read it once .
So Everything was working fine 2-3 days ago and I think my system updated something automatically or I accidentally clicked on update .
After that I keep getting this error .
[image]

After that I searched it on stack overflow and I got answers like use command `./sdkmanager --licenses` and accept the licenses . But on using that I got this error
[image]

So I searched for this error again and the answers were like don't use java 9 but I am already using java 13 so this should not cause any problem .
How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Android Studio > AVD Manager > Select the top System Image from the "Recommended" releases > Download

(2) flutter doctor --android-licenses

Comment: Its always a better answer when you explain it. Try adding an explanation of what this is.

Comment: What is it going to do ?